# What is the point from approving API access in SharePoint

Tags: azure, sharepoint, spfx

In SharePoint online, the SharePoint admin center, under API access, there is a section to approve access to external resources where that access can be specified in the configuration of an SPFx project.
Also, when we create an App Registration in Azure, we can Expose an API, and specify scopes for the token that gets issued upong authentication. We also can sepcify access in the corresponding Enterprise Application.

My question is, if both the abilities of accessing the SharePoint admin center and creating and configuring App Registrations are restricted to an Admin user, doesn't it seem redundant to give access in the SharePoint admin center?

I am trying to understand the reasoning behind this, and confirm whether my current understanding is on point.

Comment: Delegated Permissions are added to a special App Registration object called "SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal" as it is stated in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/api-access#approve-a-pending-request
You are not required to create a new app registration in order to handle requests made from currently deployed solutions or SPFx solutions. 
Thats what the API Access page is for.

Comment: @jimas13
The app you mention would be the client to the resource in this case, according to my understanding.
In the case that the resource being accessed from an SPFx webpart is an Azure Function App, and when specifying the identity provider for that Function App to be Microsoft Entra (AAD), an app registration is provisioned. Are you saying that we do not use this app for authenticating the client to the resource?

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint API Access page is essentially an simplified abstraction of the App Registration that is behind all of the SPFx (most that I am aware of) request process.

Firstly, whenever you add the below segment in you `package-solution.json`:

```
...
"webApiPermissionRequests": [
  {
    "resource": "CustomWeatherApiProxy",
    "scope": "Forecast.Read"
  }
],
...
```

You are essentially enhancing the delegated permissions of the
`SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal` App Registration as you can see in the below screen:
[image: from azure portal]

An from the API Access screen it would seem like this:
[image: from portal admin]

So the advantages for the beforementioned strategy would be that, now that I have secured my Web API with Azure Active Directory, by creating an App Registration describing my Web API and exposing a set of claims, like `Forecast.Read` for example, it is easier for me to generate code within an SPFx solution that will handle all of the Authentication/Authorization procedures before my request by just utilizing the `aadHttpClientFactory` and `AadHttpClient`, just like below:

[image: SPFx webpart render method]

The above code creates a client that will fetch the tokens needed in order to communicate with you custom resource/Web API and then uses that client in order to get some data to show on the webparts page.

So, in general, third-party solutions use the API Access mechanism in order to request the appropriate access permissions for their Apps (like access to `MS Graph`) when installed on an `App Catalog`. This way we can ensure that the installed SPFx application, that might act as a client, will have supervised access to the resources needed and will function properly.

Admins also can draw reporting data regarding which apps need access where, etc, and, last but not least, it is a way to formalize permission requests in the SharePoint Framework solutions that makes the Admin's work easy perform.

In conclusion, this is just another way of enabling access of your custom SPFx projects to resources outside of the SharePoint area.